# SSRS computed value or a maximum value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am computing a value (using some datediffs/dateadds), but I need to "cap" that value at 45. So for example, if the computed value were 78, it would still return only 45, however if the value is 31, then it would return 31. The MAX() function in SSRS is for finding the maximum of some column over many rows and that is NOT what I want. This is a computed value for ONE row that needs to be capped at 45. Any ideas?

**Note: I'd prefer not to do this in SQL itself because I am using it to change the "fill color" of a cell, but if that's the only way, I guess I can do that.

Comment: Have you looked into using IIf function in your expression to cap at 45?  example =IIf(Fields!SomeField.Value <= 45,Fields!SomeField.Value, 45)

Comment: @t_m pretty much nailed it.  You can also add his function as a calculated field in your dataset object if you feel it would make your life easier.

Comment: @kyzen..thanks. You are correct it does make sense to calculate in the dataset object to make life easier.

Comment: I've used plenty of IIFs, it's just a very large computation for the computed value that I'm doing within the same part and didn't want to have it in there twice, but oh well. I guess the ugly method is going to have to be the method! Thanks all! (t_m: if you want to put your answer as an actual answer (not a comment), I can mark it as answered then!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IIf(Fields!SomeField.Value <= 45,Fields!SomeField.Value, 45)
```

Thanks @D.R.